# composite key lookup in MS access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So I am working on a database for my company, and I have the following tables:

Countries, States, Cities, Vendors

The Cities table has an autonumbered ID, text Name, State (based on an ID from the states table), and a country (based on an ID from the countries table).  The reason it has both a city AND country is because some cities don't have a state (i.e. Dubai, Mumbai, etc.), so they are related to the state table by a state called "No State".  Because of this, the states table does not relate directly to the countries table, but can be related through the cities table.

Every vendor should belong to a city/state/country, related by that cities ID.  I want to create a composite ID with the CityID, CityState and CityCountry.  Then, within my vendor table, I want to have a lookup that puts a dropdown box of all unique city names to select, then once selected, ONLY states with that city should be allowed in the vendor state box, then ONLY countries with the given state and city would be allowed in the country box.  I want the user to see the name, but each table, including the vendor table, is actually referring to an ID.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way to structure the data to avoid this?

The company is international, and I want to be able to analyze our company's vendors at city, state, country and regional level (region to country relationship is pretty easy, so I left that out).

Comment: can't you just use simple addressline1, addressline2, postcode, city, county, country? you can then filter by either of these?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a drop down for your columns in access.  Google something like 'how to create lookup in access'.  This is very common in access and is called a 'lookup.'

As for the filtering you are trying to accomplish, how is your data configured?  do you have any relationship information for city to state or state to country?

There are data sets of cities, states and countries that may help you build these relationships (though I have no experience with these data sets...try your Google Fu to find some options).  It sounds pretty easy with the state to country relationship, but when you add cities, the list is pretty big.  And many city names show up under many different state names.

I suspect that a dynamic filtering system like what I understand you to be asking for may be complex beyond the needs of the project.

You may want to explain your requirements/objectives a little more to give me an opportunity to give you a better answer.